# Setting up an SSD drive as my main boot device

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I recently gutted my old system and I am replacing it with all new guts.
I have a 60gb SSD I will be using as my boot device and I have an internal 1.5 TB HD for storage. My internal HD is a Samsung HD154UI. My question is. Does this HD need to be set as the slave drive? Normally I'm used to HDs to have the little pin that configures your drive as a master or slave. This HD did not come with the pin. In fact instead of the traditional 8 pins. It only has 4. The first 4 are not there. I think this HD was built with just 4 pins. What do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the drive to "slave" is really a thing of the past (IDE drives).  With SATA drives they are mainly "plug and play" meaning that there is no need for master and slave.